# Want to move GET method inside POST, Volley

Tags: java, android, class, android-volley

I want to move GET method inside (if) that located inside onResponse of POST request without calling URL again because once the user post edittext php file will echo json result that will show up inside listview in activity so if call URL again in other method nothing will show up, how can I do that please?

```
public class supportActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private EditText ticketsupport;
private Button button;
private List<supportContent> con = new ArrayList<supportContent>();
private ListView supportlist;
private supportAdapter adapter;
private String ticketinput;
private String url = "http://10.0.3.2/aalm/getticket.php";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_support);

     ticketsupport = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.insertticketnumber);
     supportlist = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.supportlistview);
     adapter = new supportAdapter(this, con);
    supportlist.setAdapter(adapter);
     button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonsupprt);

    button.setOnClickListener(this);


}

private void inquiry() {

         ticketinput = ticketsupport.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest1 = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    if (response.trim().equals("responseticket")) {
                        showTicket();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(supportActivity.this, "Check the number please", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(supportActivity.this, "something wrong" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
    protected Map<String,String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
            Map<String,String> map = new HashMap<String,String>();
            map.put("ticknumber", ticketinput);
            return map;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue1 = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    requestQueue1.add(stringRequest1);

}
private void showTicket(){
        RequestQueue requestQueue2 = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("responseticket");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject ticket = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            supportContent support = new supportContent();

                            support.setTicketnumber(ticket.getString("ticketnumber"));
                            support.setSubject(ticket.getString("subject"));
                            support.setResponse(ticket.getString("response"));

                            con.add(support);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            Log.e("error", "Volley");
        }
    }
    );
    requestQueue2.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
}
 @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        inquiry();
 }
}
```

Comment: You are getting back a response from your POST request, you don't need an another GET request, just simply process the response...or I am misunderstanding something?

Comment: Just throw your whole http event inside of a method and call the method again and change your parameters to run the get event

Comment: @Jasz I don't understand could you please explain more?